# Can anyone check what's wrong with this SEDE script?

Tags: discussion

I stumbled across a meta post where I found https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/253267/people-helped-public-prototype-1

I really wanted to find the estimated number of people that I helped. But when I run it, its returning. I've tried more than 3 times but I see this everytime

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the
> operation or the server is not responding.

Can someone make this script up and running?

Answer (score 1):

The link defaults to <strike>Meta</strike> SO. Click the Meta icon next to "Switch sites:" to switch to  <strike>SO</strike> Meta, and it will work for you with your userid. I had the same problem and *am not sure why it doesn't work for  <strike>Meta</strike> SO*, but this solved the timeout issue for me.

[image: Red paint circle around button to click]

The query works without issue on <strike>SO</strike> Meta.

**Edit:** Thank you Anna for clarifying--I'm not sure if my answer is still helpful because it fixes the query for Meta SO *rather than* SO, but I will leave it for now in case anyone wants to see how metahelpful they are.

Comment: The meta icon is just a shortcut for switching *to* meta. The query is actually running on SO. You can see it from the URL - `http://data.stackexchange.com/**stackoverflow**/query/253267/people-helped-public-prototype-1`. The timeout may be related to your specific user activity on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that, as I was about to ask a question about why SEDE thought it was searching SO when the Meta icon was displayed.